# Reading simple data files manipulating strings.

Tags: python

If I'm given:

```
 point_loads, 3, 500
 point_loads, 6, 900
 point_loads, 12, 300
```

This code:

```
 for line in open("Input.txt"):
      li=line.strip()
      if li.startswith("point_load"):
         l = li.split(',')
         for num in l[1:]:
             num = float(num.strip())
             point_loads.append(num)
```

prints:

```
 point_loads = [3, 500, 6, 900, 12, 300]
```

I am trying to modify it so that if I'm given:

```
 length = 32

 point_loads, 3, 500
 point_loads, 6, 900
 point_loads, end, 300
```

It will set 'end' equal to 32 (or the variable length) so that the output is:

```
 point_loads = [3, 500, 6, 900, 32, 300]
```

I tried a few different things, this was my latest...

```
 for line in open("Input.txt"):
      li=line.strip()
      if li.startswith("point_load"):
         l = li.split(',')
         for num in l[1:]:
             if num == 'end':
                  num = 10
             num = float(num.strip())
             point_loads.append(num)
```

but it gave me the error: (plus it wouldn't have really have done what I wanted, but it was a start)

```
     num = float(num.strip())
     ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'end'
```

When debugging, I can see that I need to strip the string so that it doesnt preform an operation on  '   end'.

I've tried messing around with different bits of code for a few hours now, but have made no progress.

Any tips for this part?

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with your second bit? As you found, stripping ' end' first will allow it to properly assign `num = 10`, thus replacing the text end with a given variable. What isn't working about that approach?

Comment: I think I know how to do it in my head, but putting that in code is the roadblock for me right now. I know I need to strip it of its white space before I compare it, but don't know how to code it. Playing around with examples I've seen online hasn't proved to be helpful, so I posted here as a last resort.

Comment: num = num.strip() before your if statement? It might be easier to look into the csv module too.

Comment: I tried this a while a go, but it gave me this error:                                                                                                       num = float(num.strip())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: You are close, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure. But it might what you want?

```
for line in open("Input.txt"):
    li = line.strip()
    if li.startswith("point_load"):
        l = li.split(', ')
        for num in l[1:]:
            if num == 'end':
                num = '10'
            num = float(num.strip())
            point_loads.append(num)
```

1. `l = li.split(',')` turns to `l = li.split(', ')`, use both `,` and  to split string to list
2. `num = 10` turns to `num = '10'` make all elements are string to call `strip()`

Comment: I see. Thank you for the description. I get an error though,                                                             num = float(num.strip())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'end'

Comment: what's your python version?

Comment: it's version 3.6.1

Comment: I tried it on python on 3.6 and 2.7 again, it works.please refer to https://ideone.com/9z7xxO

Comment: I tried the code you posted and it works in 3.6.1 as well. When I use the open(file.txt)..., it doesn't work. Must be something to do with that. I'll fiddle around with it and see what I can come up with. Thank you for your help.

Comment: would you check the "end" in file.txt is upper case or lower case? Is the case matched?  or make `open("Input.txt")` to `open("Input.txt", "r")`.  Maybe you should print the `num` to check what is Python see.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thank you so much! The num = num.strip() before the if statement fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you are unable to exchange the string 'end' with a variable of your choosing. Based on what you've said, it's because you are not matching strings correctly first. When you split the line by comma, you are still getting whitespace for each item.

`'point_loads, end, 300'.split()` ends up as `['point_loads', ' end', ' 300']

In order to fix this I would first filter your lines to strip all whitespace from each item after the split. Then when you test `if num == 'end'` you will get `True`. Your current code is testing `if 'end' == ' end'` which is `False`.

```
point_loads = []

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        li = line.strip()
        if li.startswith("point_load"):
            l = li.split(',')
            l = [x.strip() for x in l]  # strip whitespace from each item
            for num in l[1:]:
                if num == 'end':
                    num = 10.
                else:
                    num = float(num.strip())
                point_loads.append(num)
```

I noticed the second part of your problem has to do with the nature of Python and duck typing. You are trying to call a string method strip() on ints and strings. In my above code if it matches your string it assigns an int otherwise it will convert the string to an int thus avoiding the issue of trying to call strip on an int.

*EDIT* I fixed the code - I had made a typo and used `split()` instead of `strip()` in the list comprehension. I tested this in python3.6 but it should also work in python2.7. I added a proper context manager for opening the file too which you should always do.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This is giving me this error though:                                                                                       num = float(num.strip())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'